# Migrate to Magento 1.9.3 or Magento 2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-1.7, migration

We have websites that are currently using Magento 1.7. We are planning to migrate most of these Magento Websites to Magento 1.9.3, some are suggesting to move it to Magento 2.

We are moving because we need to get the latest patches/fixes/features introduced in the new released of Magento 1 series (the Magento 1.9.3). My question is, it is worth to upgrade to Magento 2 from Magento 1.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although some have reservations about moving to Magento 2, it’s clear Magento 2 platform was designed to provide a better experience for customers and admin. It maintains the flexibility Magento is known for, but adds some important, useful features.

The new version is able to grow as businesses grow. It’s fast with a streamlined checkout process to increase conversions and encourage repeat customers.

Experts believe businesses will move to Magento 2 from either Magento 1, other ecommerce platforms, or to start brand-new online stores. To keep up, the wealth of extensions available must be upgraded to the new version.